# how to check if a row in a database contains a certain value

Tags: java, android, database, android-sqlite

I have been experimenting with **SQLite databases** and I was wondering if you could **search** through a database for a certain value and include that in an if statement saying if this value exists within the database then say the database already has this value else add the value to the database?

database:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DB_NAME = "License.db";
private static final String TABLE_LICENSE = "License";
private static final String DB_ID = "_id";
private static final String DB_License = "LicenseNum";


public DatabaseHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, factory, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "Create Table " + TABLE_LICENSE + "(" +
            DB_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " +
            DB_License + " TEXT " +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + TABLE_LICENSE);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addLicense(Licenses license) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DB_License, license.get_License());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_LICENSE, null, values);
    db.close();

}

public String databaseToString() {

    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LICENSE + " WHERE 1";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    c.moveToFirst();

    while (!c.isAfterLast()){
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LicenseNum"))!= null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LicenseNum"));
            dbString += "/n";
        }
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}

public Cursor contain(String Num){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery(Num, null);
}

}
```

code (Class ="Licenses"):

```
public class Licenses
{

private int _id;
private String _License;

public Licenses(String License) {
    this._License = License;
}

public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public String get_License() {
    return _License;
}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public void set_License(String _License) {
    this._License = _License;
}

}
```

code (Class ="License_Plate"):

```
public class License_Plate extends AppCompatActivity {
public static EditText License;
public static Button Set;
public static   String[] PlateNum = new String[1000];
private TextView LPN3;
private TextView LPN2;
private Button seedb;
private TextView dbtable;
private Button back;
private DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
Context context;
SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory;
String name = "License.db";
int version = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_license__plate);
    License = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LPN);
    Set = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Set);
    seedb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seedb);
    dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context,name,factory,version);
}

public void Onclickone(View v){
    try {


        String Plate = License.getText().toString().toUpperCase().trim();
        String Extra = Plate + " Has been added to your array";
        String Extra2 = Plate + " is already part of Your license plates";
        String query = "Select * From License where name = '" + Plate + "'";
        if (dbHandler.contain(query).getCount() < 0 && Plate.length() >= 1 
&& Plate.length() <= 7) {
            setContentView(R.layout.add);
            LPN3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Added);
            Licenses Licensess = new 
Licenses(License.getText().toString().toUpperCase().trim());
            dbHandler.addLicense(Licensess);
            printDatabase();

        } else if (dbHandler.contain(query).getCount() > 0 && Plate.length() 
>= 1 && Plate.length() <= 7) {
            setContentView(R.layout.have);
            LPN2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Have);
            LPN2.setText(License.getText() + " is already part of your 
license plates");

        }
    } catch (Exception e){

Toast.makeText(License_Plate.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void Onclicktwo(View v){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_license__plate);
    License = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LPN);
    Set = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Set);
    seedb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seedb);
}

public void Onclickthree(View v){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_license__plate);
    License = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LPN);
    Set = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Set);
    seedb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seedb);
}

public void onclick4(View v){
    setContentView(R.layout.database);
    dbtable = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dbtxt);
    printDatabase();
}

public void onclick5(View v){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_license__plate);
    License = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LPN);
    Set = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Set);
    seedb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seedb);
}

public void printDatabase(){
    String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
    dbtable.setText(dbString);
}

}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw3lv.png)

If anyone can help please do. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please check [how to ask on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Post the codes that you've tried

Comment: now I am getting the error I have just posted in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You already have a `SELECT` clause but it's wrong, so change:

```
String query = "Select * From License where name = '" + Plate + "'";
```

to:

```
String query = "Select * From License where LicenseNum = '" + Plate + "'";
```

although having hardcoded the column names and the table name is not a good practice.

If this statement does not return any rows then the `Plate` dos not exist in the table.